# Error in running a simple watir script: uninitialized constant Watir::IE (NameError)

Tags: ruby, windows-7, 64-bit, watir, watir-webdriver

I have installed Ruby 2, devkit & Watir.

- enviroment:              OS win7(64bit）
- installation files:

  - rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p0-x64.exe
  - DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe
- part of gem list result:

  - commmonwatir 4.0.0
  - watir 4.0.0
  - win32-process 0.6.6

when I running a simple script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver' 
ie = Watir::IE.new
ie.goto("http://www.google.com")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Watir::IE (NameError)
```

then I tried `ie = Watir::Browser.new` instead of `ie = Watir::IE.new`
still getting error:

```
cannot load such file watir-classic (loaderror)
```

then I tried installing watir-classic, getting error again:

```
extconf.rb
libxml2 is missing
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Generally speaking either `require 'watir'` or `require 'watir-webdriver'` but not both.  use one or the other for your tests.  watir = classic IE only watir.  watir-webdriver = webdriver based watir with cross browser support

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden, `require 'watir'` is no longer just classic IE. Watir is now a metagem that will load watir-classic or watir-webdriver depending on the browser that you want to use.

Comment: So if you are using `require 'watir'`, do you still need to `require 'watir-webdriver'`?

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden, no you do not need `require 'watir-webdriver'`. If you are using the latest watir gem version, you should only ever need to do `require 'watir'`.

Comment: In your gem list result: watir-classic is absent. Please install watir-classic by using <gem install watir-classic --no-rdoc --no-ri> . then add require 'watir-classic' , no need require 'watir-webdriver'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error, my guess is that watir-classic is failing to install the nokogiri gem. Nokogiri does not currently support Ruby x64 on Windows - see https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/864.

Two things you could try:

1. Use 32bit Ruby (as suggested in the Nokogiri issue)
2. Use a browser other than IE. By default, `Browser.new` will start IE using watir-classic. Using one of the other browsers will use watir-webdriver, which I do not believe is dependent on nokogiri.

Example:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have read the https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/864.

Comment: I used 32bit Ruby and my problem was solved. Thank you again. The second suggession seems to work too but need other things to install for specific browser.

Comment: better than not accepting at all, which a lot of new users seem to do. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You do not have watir-webdriver installed (or at least listed in your gem list result).

```
gem install watir-webdriver
```

The script:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
ie = Watir::Browser.new :ie
ie.goto("http://www.google.com")
```

Source: http://watirwebdriver.com

If you'd prefer watir-classic you can find installation and quick start information here: https://github.com/watir/watir-classic

Comment: I do have watir-webdriver installed. I have taken the advice of Justin Ko and used 32bit Ruby. The problem was sovled. thank you any way.

Comment: The section of `gem list` results that you showed did not list 'watir-webdriver' making it appear to us that the gem was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code remove require 'watir-webdriver' and add require 'watir-classic' . So, your code should be as below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-classic'
ie = Watir::IE.new
ie.goto("http://www.google.com")
```

Warning notification: Watir::IE constant is deprecated, use Watir::Browser instead
In this case no need require 'watir-classic'. The following code should work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
#require 'watir-classic'
#ie = Watir::IE.new
ie = Watir::Browser.new
ie.goto("http://www.google.com")
```